# Any idea how to evaluate this equation?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to evaluate(approximate) the following integral

$$ F(x,t;q) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{q}{q+2ik} e^{i(kx +8k^3 t)}\; dk $$
It's similar to the Airy function but I can't get rid of the $\frac{1}{k}$ in front of the exponential.

$q>0 $ is a parameter that I can vary.
$x \in (-\infty,\infty)$ is my spatial variable
$t > 0$ is my time dependence

Any ideas?

An approximate solution in the large or small $q$ limit would also be fine.

Comment: and what is the meaning of the variables?

Comment: I've added some more detail

Comment: I doubt that this integral has any explicit formula (would be glad to be wrong, of course).

Comment: An approximation would be good too

Comment: Using Cauchy's theorem, you can certainly express this integral in terms of real exponentials (cubic and all).  The resulting integral, however, is quite nasty-looking and not very promising.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-it}$ is the CF of the [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) while $e^{ik^3}$ is the Fourier transform of the Airy function $Ai(-x)$, your integral is a convolution integral that can be evaluated through the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $E_{n}(x)$ for $n=-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{2}{3}$ or just through the [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) $\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3},x\right),\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3},x\right).$